# Refactor impure recursion with state monad?

Tags: haskell, recursion, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I've been dissecting [this one-liner solution](https://github.com/kaathewise/aoc2022/blob/main/14.py) for [aoc day 14](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/14) and came across an elegant impure recursive solution:

```py
def s(x,y):
    if y > h: return True
    if (x, y) in m: return False
    return next((r for d in (0,-1,1) if (r:=s(x+d,y+1))), None) or m.add((x,y))
```

[full solution on godbolt](https://python.godbolt.org/z/7WoW5axnb)

One way you could make this pure is by explicitly passing and returning the set `m` from the function `s` (i.e. `s :: int -> int -> set -> (bool, set)`).

However, I've also read about how the [reader/writer](https://mmhaskell.com/monads/reader-writer)/[state](https://mmhaskell.com/monads/state) monads save you from having to pass the extra parameter and handle the tuple result an am interested in porting this recursion to haskell.

I found a haskell [solution](https://github.com/ephemient/aoc2022/blob/main/hs/src/Day14.hs) on the reddit that looks like it may do the same recursion (as well as [two](https://github.com/ehllie/aoc2022/blob/main/aoc14/Main.hs) [more](https://github.com/fapete/advent_of_code/blob/master/2022/day14/day14.hs) that don't).

```hs
fill :: (MArray a Bool (ST s), Ix i, Num i, Show i) => a (i, i) Bool -> i -> ST s (Int, Int)
fill blocks maxY = do
    counterAtMaxY <- newSTRef Nothing
    counter <- newSTRef 0
    let fill' (x, y) = readArray blocks (x, y) >>= flip bool (pure ()) do
            when (y == maxY) $ readSTRef counterAtMaxY >>= maybe
                (readSTRef counter >>= writeSTRef counterAtMaxY . Just) (const $ pure ())
            when (y <= maxY) $ fill' (x, y + 1) >> fill' (x - 1, y + 1) >> fill' (x + 1, y + 1)
            writeArray blocks (x, y) True >> modifySTRef' counter (+ 1)
    fill' (500, 0)
    counterAtMaxY <- readSTRef counterAtMaxY
    counter <- readSTRef counter
    pure (fromMaybe counter counterAtMaxY, counter)
```

[full solution on godbolt](https://haskell.godbolt.org/z/P8MThhhs1)

Could someone confirm that this indeed is a port of the python solution. If so could they baby me through following how the recursion is happening?

I still am not Haskell literate. I can kind of make out that `fill' (500, 0)` means `m >>= \_ -> fill' (500, 0)`, which means discard the current state, and create a new monad independently (something gets preserved but I'm confused what)??.  I also don't understand monad transformers at all.

The Haskell solution does part 2 of the question simultaneously, so maybe someone can factor that out so there's no confusion between the cartesian coordinates and the pair of ints containing the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a fairly close translation of your Python code to Haskell. Some remarks on the differences:

- The global `h` becomes a local parameter, and `m :: Set (Int, Int)` gets passed implicitly in the `State` monad, accessed using `get` and `modify`.
- There is no early return in Haskell (calling `return`/`pure` doesn't abort the rest of the function, you have to put it at the end of the block). On the other hand, `if` expressions must have an `else` clause, so that forces you to do the right thing anyway.
- The generator expression can be written as a higher-order function which tries each action in a list, stopping as soon as one returns `True`.
- the `add` function in Python returns `None`, which gets interpreted as `False` in conditionals. In Haskell we don't like this kind of overloading; instead, we explicitly attach the `False` value to the value-less action `add (x, y)`, `add (x, y) *> pure False`.
- Use `execState` to "run the monadic program" `s h0 500 0` with an initial state `m0`, obtaining its final state. That "program" `s h0 500 0 :: M Bool` is actually a pure function `Set (Int, Int) -> (Bool, Set (Int, Int))`, and all `execState` does is to apply that to the initial state and project out the second component of the output pair. The point of the "state monad" is that such a function can be defined with the syntax of an imperative language ("do-notation").

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

type M = State (Set (Int, Int))

s :: Int -> Int -> Int -> M Bool
s h x y =
  if y > h then pure True
  else do
    m <- get
    if Set.member (x, y) m then
      pure False
    else
      orM ([s h (x+d) (y+1) | d <- [0, -1, 1]] ++ [add (x, y) *> pure False])

orM :: Monad m => [m Bool] -> m Bool
orM [] = pure False
orM (x : xs) = do
  b <- x
  if b then pure True
  else orM xs

add :: (Int, Int) -> M ()
add (x, y) = modify (Set.insert (x, y))

-- Example from https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/14

m0 :: Set (Int, Int)
m0 = vline 498 4 6 <> hline 498 496 6 <> hline 503 502 4 <> vline 502 4 9 <> hline 494 502 9

vline, hline :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Set (Int, Int)
vline x y1 y2 | y1 > y2 = vline x y2 y1
vline x y1 y2 = Set.fromList [(x, y) | y <- [y1 .. y2]]

hline x1 x2 y | x1 > x2 = hline x2 x1 y
hline x1 x2 y = Set.fromList [(x, y) | x <- [x1 .. x2]]

h0 :: Int
h0 = 9

main :: IO ()
main =
  print (Set.size (execState (s h0 500 0) m0) - Set.size m0)
  -- Output: 24
```

Comment: haha, I should have definitely renamed those one letter variable names before posting

Comment: After writing some [notes](https://gist.github.com/tom-huntington/c0ce6115fa1cf218ce4567a1154f47af) I'm starting to see how a lazy computation/monadic program is being built up by `s h0 500 0`. The laziness is hard to get your head around at first

Comment: once `if y > h then pure True` gets hit, then `if b then pure True` will always be hit for the remainder of the program, and `add (x, y)` is never evaluated again

Answer (score 2):

(partial answer only: below I only clarify the Haskell code, but I did not compare it against the Python code or the task)

I kind of dislike the Haskell code. I believe it aims at pointfree style too much. I mean, `flip bool` to avoid a variable? `maybe` between two complex branches? Nah, I'd use use a plain `if`/`case`.

Still, it's working in the `ST s` monad, so it reads like imperative code. The state is never discarded, only modified as in imperative languages. Read `a >>= b` roughly like `result = a() ; b(result)` except the code stubbornly avoids to introduce the variable `result`.

Here is the code, rewritten to (IMHO) improve readability.

```
fill :: (MArray a Bool (ST s), Ix i, Num i, Show i) 
     => a (i, i) Bool -> i -> ST s (Int, Int)
fill blocks maxY = do
    counterAtMaxY <- newSTRef Nothing
    counter <- newSTRef 0
    let fill' (x, y) = do
           -- test the boolean flag at (x,y)
           b <- readArray blocks (x, y)
           -- if false, we did not visit (x,y) before
           when (not b) $ do
              when (y == maxY) $ do
                 -- if counterAtMaxY is Nothing,
                 -- replace it with counter
                 mayc <- readSTRef counterAtMaxY
                 case mayc of
                    Nothing -> do
                       c <- readSTRef counter
                       writeSTRef counterAtMaxY (Just c)
                    Just _ -> pure ()
              when (y <= maxY) $ do
                 -- recurse thrice
                 fill' (x, y + 1)
                 fill' (x - 1, y + 1)
                 fill' (x + 1, y + 1)
            -- mark (x,y) as visited
            writeArray blocks (x, y) True
            -- increment counter
            modifySTRef' counter (+ 1)
    fill' (500, 0)
    counterAtMaxY <- readSTRef counterAtMaxY
    counter <- readSTRef counter
    pure (fromMaybe counter counterAtMaxY, counter)
```

I'd also rewrite the `y == maxY` case as follows:

```
when (y == maxY) $ do
   -- if counterAtMaxY is Nothing,
   -- replace it with counter
   c <- readSTRef counter       
   modify counterAtMaxY $ \mayc ->
      case mayc of
         Nothing -> Just c
         Just _ -> mayc
```

or even

```
when (y == maxY) $ do
   -- if counterAtMaxY is Nothing,
   -- replace it with counter
   c <- readSTRef counter       
   modify counterAtMaxY (<|> Just c)
```

where `(<|> Just c)` is a function acting as the identity on `Just _` values, but mapping `Nothing` to `Just c`, which is similar to the Python `... or c`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll need some time to get my head around `ST`. Although, I found a Fibonacci example that looks simpler https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad/ST